# How can I use both Intel onboard and Nvidia graphics at the same time?

Tags: xorg, nvidia, intel-graphics

How can I use both Intel onboard graphic chip and nVidia card at the same time?
I googled a little and lots of people said I need SLI or crossfire support for both of my cards, but I managed to do so in Win 7 so I guess it could be done in Ubuntu.

Here's some information of my computer, any help?

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G94 [GeForce 9600 GT]
       vendor: nVidia Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff     memory:f8000000-f9ffffff ioport:af00(size=128) memory:fb000000-fb07ffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 10
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:43 memory:fdf00000-fdf7ffff ioport:ff00(size=8) memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fdc00000-fdcfffff
```

Comment: ...you can't =)

Answer (score 1):

With the current graphics platform, this does not seem to be possible. You can only use one card